# Pandas column compare

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
f = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM mydata', engine, index_col='Date')

f['SMA_100'] = talib.SMA(numpy.asarray(f['Settle']), 100)
f['SMA_200'] = talib.SMA(numpy.asarray(f['Settle']), 200)

print(f['SMA_100'])

2017-05-17    2333.4155
2017-05-18    2334.4630
2017-05-19    2335.6780
Name: SMA_100, dtype: float64

print(f['SMA_200'])

2017-05-17    2251.68320
2017-05-18    2252.73695
2017-05-19    2253.85945
Name: SMA_200, dtype: float64
```

How can I catch the values in the second columns in x and y variable and compare them. For example:

```
if x > y:
    do something
```

where x and y are the values of the second column . I tried:

```
if f['SMA_100'] > f['SMA_200']:
    do something
```

but of course it is not working.

Comment: What is "do something" supposed to do? Operate on the values that meet the condition?

Comment: Please post your full script. What is `pd` (I assume its Pandas)? And what is `talib`?

Comment: This has to do with comparing columns in pandas, you should post a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve with sample data instead of making calls to a database that other users cannot use and cluttering the example with logic from `talib`

Comment: 2017-05-17    2333.4155    2017-05-17    2251.68320. In this case x = 2333.4155 and y = 2251.6835. And the logic is If x > y on that date then open long position. And yes pd is Pandas and talib is python module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ MSeifert asked, it really depends what "do something" means. Assuming you
are looking to create some trade logic by looking at moving averages of what I
assume is the Settlement Price, you could do something like

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[5, 2, 7],'B':[8,1,3]}, index=['t1', 't2', 't3'])

idx = df.loc[:, 'A'] > df.loc[:, 'B']
df.loc[:,'Trade'] = idx * 10

print(df)
   A  B  Trade
t1  5  8      0
t2  2  1     10
t3  7  3     10
```

if instead you need some path dependant logic, you could look through the
boolean values of idx, e.g.

```
for time, istrue in idx.iteritems():
    if istrue:
        print("Doing something at %s" % time)

Doing something at t2
Doing something at t3
```

The reason you get an error when you try

```
if f['SMA_100'] > f['SMA_200']:
    pass
```

is that this resolves to something like

```
if idx:
    pass
```

which is asking whether

```
print(idx)
t1    False
t2     True
t3     True
dtype: bool
```

is True or False? As the `ValueError` indicates,
`The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.`